# jQuery .post is working but triggering .fail without any information

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-domain, .post

I've got my data posting successfully but I'm not having any luck getting my .post response handler code to work. I get inconsistent results in the different browsers/tools I've tried. Here's the post code:

```
$.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), "json")
   .done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      alert('done');
   })
   .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // log the error to the console
      alert('responsetext:' + jqXHR.responseText + ', status:' + textStatus + ', error:' + errorThrown);
   })
```

In FireFox and Chrome it always goes to the .fail (even though the data is successfully posting) but the only item set is textStatus to "error". In Firefox when I try to view the response it just shows the Error, "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1". In Chrome, in the Console I'm seeing this: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.net/applicationsvc/formprocessor/index.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.net' is therefore not allowed access." Which seems very relevant but my attempts to solve it haven't worked.

How can I resolve the Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue in a .post? Why aren't I getting any error data and why is FireFox unable to parse the response.

Using PostMan, and using the same headers and body, I do see I'm getting a response of:

```
{"successful":true,"thankyou_message":"<h2>Thank you!<\/h2><p>Thank you for signing up!<\/p>"}
```

But the code doesn't seem to be getting or handling that.

Here are the Request headers that are going out:

```
Host: example.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://example.net/mypage.htm
Content-Length: 655
Origin: http://example.net
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

UPDATE:
I've now switched from the .post to .ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr("action"),
    type: "POST",
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
        alert('done');
    }
});
```

With that I get a consistent HTTP 501 Response.

Comment: Please add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before print the json response

Comment: Are you calling cross origin? That means even if the server is the same, the protocol and portname has to be too

Comment: yes, it is cross origin. Different servers.

Comment: the cross origin thing makes me wonder but the thing is, the post is successful so the server isn't blocking the post, I'm just not able to handle the response and I don't get that.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.2 . There's some problem with headers you are sending.

Comment: You can not make the call because it is cross domain. Simple as that. Unless you enabled CORS on the other server, you can not make an Ajax call. You can make a JSONP call, but the other server needs to be able to do that. And a JSONP call needs to be a GET, not a post.

Comment: epascarello - I think you're probably right but what I don't get is why is the data successfully posting? The only problem is the response. I can just wrap the post in a try block and show the thank you message in the finally and all works, it's just too hacky for my tastes.

Comment: If the call fails, you may actually post the html form instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cross domain then try with the JSONP instea

Your Code

```
$.ajax({
     url: form.attr("action"),
     method: "POST",
     headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"},
     data: form.serialize(),
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function () {
         alert('done');
     }
});
```

Change it to

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr("action"),
    type: "POST",
    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"},
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
        alert('done');
    }
});
```

Comment: In the .Ajax call I replaced the .post with as stated in my update above, I explicitly specified contentType: application/json, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you please give me site url so i will check

Comment: @EfficionDave if you are using cross browsing then try with JSONP instead of the JSON

Comment: I have trace the url you are posting the data on the url : http://email.weissman.net/applicationsvc/formprocessor/index.php which not working on normal browser. so please contact to email.weissman.net support

Comment: I have see the code there is problem with data posting i have see your code i am updating ans

Comment: i have change `method: "POST"` to `type: "POST",`

Comment: A JSONP call is a GET request, not a post.

Comment: I had it as type: "POST" before changing it to method: "POST" both still submitted as GET if jsonp was the dataType.

Answer (score 0):

try to enable cross-origin on the server, example in php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

the server must send this in the response header, change the star accordingly to your domain for security reasons.

Comment: I can't change things on the server.

Comment: Too bad, maybe they intentionally block it, if not, they should allow posts from your domain.